# Determine IndexSet to Delete Core Data Entry?

Tags: indexing, swiftui, unique-constraint

I have implemented .onDelete on a Core Data list and it is working OK:

```
                List {
                    ForEach(roundsData.roundsData, id: \.self) { item in
                        NavigationLink {
                            SavedRoundEdit(item: item)
                        } label: {
                            RoundsList(item: item)
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                        roundsData.deleteRound(indexSet: indexS
                    })
                }
```

Here is the delete function and it works fine using .onDelete:

```
    func deleteRound(indexSet: IndexSet) {
        guard let index = indexSet.first else { return }
        let entity = roundsData[index]
        managedObjectContext.delete(entity)
    }
```

The NavigationLink goes to a detailed view of that List item to enable editing of the saved data.

After the data is edited in that view, if I save the edited data, the original entry is still there.  I need to delete the original entity prior to saving the updated, edited data.  I have CloudKit enabled, so I cannot use "unique constraints" to ensure there are no duplicates.

How do I determine the IndexSet for the entity after navigating to the detailed view for editing, to then use my *deleteRound* function to delete the original entry prior to saving the new, edited data?

Comment: You have to **save** the context to delete the data permanently.

Comment: Thanks, vadian.  Sorry I should have included that I do save the context to delete the data permanently. `    func saveRounds() {
        guard managedObjectContext.hasChanges else { return }
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
            fetchRounds()
        } catch let error {
            print("Error saving. \(error)")
        }
    }`, which is called immediately aft the _deleteRound_ call.  Question is how to determine the IndexSet for the List element to pass to _deleteRound_?